# SRID issues with GeoDjango on MySQL 8

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, geospatial, geodjango

GeoDjango is not respecting SRIDs with MySQL 8.

I created a new column

`geo_code = PointField(srid=4326)`

and ran `makemigrations`. Running `sqlmigrate` on the generated migration gives

```
BEGIN;
--
-- Create model Location
--
CREATE TABLE `locations_location` (`id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, `geo_code` POINT NOT NULL);
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX `locations_location_geo_code_id` ON `locations_location`(`geo_code`);
COMMIT;
```

See how the SRID was ignored.

Now anything I add to this column is using SRID 0 - which is incorrect. I get wrong results if I use the `ST_DISTANCE` function with SRID 0.

I tried using `migrations.SeparateDatabaseAndState` to create the column with the correct SRID constraint with the following SQL

```
ALTER TABLE backend_userprofile ADD COLUMN geocode_point POINT NULL SRID 4326;
```

Now if I try inserting data into this column I get the following error

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (3643, "The SRID of the geometry does not match the SRID of the
column 'geo_code'. The SRID of the geometry is 0, but the SRID of the column is 4326. 
Consider changing the SRID of the geometry or the SRID property of the column.")
```

Django is still trying to insert data with SRID 0 and MySQL raises and error because the column has a constrain on SRID.

Is there a way to make Django work with correct SRIDs?

Comment: Great question, what did you end up doing? This is a blocker for me

Comment: @fmalina We ended up overriding the default GIS backend class (MySQLDatabaseWrapper) to tell Django what operations work with the DB (MySQL8 for us).

Comment: Makes sense, I contributed such patches in the past, would you mind forking Django on Github and send a PR with your changes, so you don't have to monkey patch forever plus I get access too. I'd help triage your patch. I am @fmalina on Github so just mention me. GeoDjango MySQL users are few and far in between

Answer (score 0):

This is far from ideal solution, but may help in some cases

Let's imagine you have model `X` with `coordinate` as a `gis_models.PointField` with srid=4326

**First:**
replace field definition in the `models.py` to the simple `CharField`

```
# coordinate = gis_models.PointField(blank=True, null=True, srid=4326)
coordinate = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

**Then** introduce custom definition of `ST_GeomFromText` function:

```
class ST_GeomFromText(Func):
    function = "ST_GeomFromText"
    template = "%(function)s(%(field)s, %(srid)s)"
    output_field = PointField()

    def __init__(self, expression, srid, **extra):
        super().__init__(expression, srid=srid, **extra)
```

**and then** whenever you need to update the existing field use smth like this:

```
x.coordinate = ST_GeomFromText(Point(lat, lng), srid=4326)
x.save()
```

and it will work

this approach for sure unproductive if you need this field as point field bc of some other logic but if you have "write-only" or limited "read only" it will work